# Where is the cl::Program::Sources defined?

Tags: c++, constructor, opencl, gpgpu

I am looking at an OpenCL Hello World program source and many use a similar variation of the line:

```
cl::Program::Sources sources( 1, std::make_pair(src.c_str(), src.length() + 1));
```

Where is this constructor defined? The closest I can find is constructor for Program.

```
cl::Program::Program(const Context& context, const STRING_CLASS& source, bool build, cl_int * err = NULL)
```

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-cplusplus-1.2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Sources is a typedef inside the Program class like this (check page 28):

```
typedef VECTOR_CLASS<std::pair<const char*, ::size_t> > Sources
```

So, in the code that you have shown, a sources object is created, not a Program object.